# Angular Navigation bar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, navigationbar

I want to call the navigation bar on different components, same for footer also. For, some component I don't need to render header and footer.

If I call the header and footer in app.component.html then it will render in all pages.

How can I make the navbar and footer disable when I call some specific componenet.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno in how many component you need to hide heder and footer. I can imagine components like login, register or somehting like that.

So in that case i would go with ngif.

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="showNav"></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer *ngIf="showFooter"></app-footer>
```

And create or add logic in app.component.ts to hide or show header and footer based on your route.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // set default boolean value to showNav and Footer
  showNav = true;
  showFooter = true;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // Check the router events for navigation changes.
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // Hide the nav and footer on specific routes.
        const hideOnRoutes = ['/login', '/register']; // Add more routes here as needed.
        this.showNav = !hideOnRoutes.includes(event.urlAfterRedirects);
        this.showFooter = !hideOnRoutes.includes(event.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a service to handle data common to the whole application (for example shared-data , with the command `ng generate service shared-data`). When the service is created, add a property to manage the visibility of the header and footer (e.g. showHeaderFooter)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedDataService {
  public showHeaderFooter: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Then, control the visibility of these by adding an ngIf with the new property in the new service. In the component, you need to import in the constructor the service you have created.
This in the app.component.html for the header (the same for the footer):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="sharedDataService.showHeaderFooter">
   <app-header></app-header>
</ng-container>
```

In the app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }

}
```

Finally, control in the ngOnInit of the components this variable to decide if the header and footer are shown or not. For example:

with-header-footer.component.ts file :

```
export class WithHeaderFooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.sharedDataService.showHeaderFooter = true;
  }
}
```

without-header-footer.component.ts file:

```
export class WithoutHeaderFooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.sharedDataService.showHeaderFooter = false;
  }
}
```